# Error importing app in pytest fixtures

Tags: python, pytest

> client_fixture.py

```
import pytest

from app.apis import api
from app import create_app


@pytest.fixture
def app_client(credentials, redis_cred_setup):
    app = create_app(credentials['app_config_name'])
    api.init_app(app)

    client = app.test_client()
    return client
```

I have fixture and function `create_app()` inside `__init__.py` in `app` package

but this fixture raise an error

`ImportError: Error importing plugin "client_fixtures": No module named 'app'`

package structure

```
Core
    app-
        ...
        __init__.py

    tests-
        client_fixture.py
```

> Maybe it will be helpful

When I run tests using PyCharm, everything working
I just clicking right mouse button on tests folder and execute `Run py.test in tests'

Comment: How and from which working directory did you start the tests?

Comment: Edited @KlausD.
I run my program using `pytest` command from Core dir.

Comment: You will have to run the tests from the `Core` directory.

Comment: This is what I am doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `pytest` like:

```
python -m pytest tests/
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html):

> This is almost equivalent to invoking the command line script `pytest tests/` directly, except that Python will also add the current directory to sys.path.

Comment: Thank you :) you save my email from Gitlab spam))